# Tab key getting bounded to forward-button

Tags: indentation, region, tabs

Launching `emacs` with the `-Q` option (default settings) shows TAB being correctly bound to `indent-for-tab-command`. If I launch `emacs` without the -Q, TAB is always being bound to `forward-button` which is absolutely *not* what I want.

I've commented everything out of my `~/.emacs` file and the problem is still persisting. What could be changing the `TAB` key behavior?

Comment: Could it be that your new Emacs is some older version?

Comment: Check the key binding for TAB using e.g. `C-h k TAB`. By default this will tell you that (in Emacs 25 at least) TAB is bound to `indent-for-tab-command`, which would allow you to select the region and indent. If it is bound to something else you'll need to sort out where in your configuration that is happening. You can try starting Emacs with the -Q option (which skips your personal confiugration) to confirm the default behavior.

Comment: @glucas thanks for that suggestion, turns out the default assignment is correct, but for whatever reason, if I do not launch with the -Q option, TAB ends up being bound to `forward-button`!  I've since commented out everything from my `~/.emacs` file and it still gets bound to `forward-button`, where else could this be set?  I'll update the question

Comment: How about if you run emacs with `-q` (vs. `-Q`)? That skips your init file but loads other things like site-lisp files, which might be changing things. You can also try fixing the binding in your .emacs with `(global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'indent-for-tab-command)`.

Comment: Also note that tab does get bound to `forward-button` by default in some modes such as `help-mode`.

Comment: @glucas so lower case `-q` has it bound to `forward-button` - where can I find these site-lisp files?

Comment: Since the comment thread is getting long I've converted this to an answer and added some info about the site files. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you can check the binding of the TAB key using `C-h k TAB`. Try starting emacs with `-Q` and `-q` to help narrow down where the binding might be set.

With `-Q` Emacs skips all local init files so you'll get the default behavior. Tab should be bound to `indent-for-tab-command`. With `-q` Emacs skips your personal init file but will still load any site files.

Refer to [the Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File) for details about what files are loaded at startup. There may be `site-start.el` or `default.el` files on your load path that are changing things. You'll want to check the load path (`C-h v load-path`) to see where such files might be found -- typically there is a `site-lisp` directory in your Emacs installation directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you experienced before or are expecting now, but you can do either of these things to indent the selected text (region):

- **`C-M-\`** (`indent-region`): Indent the region text either according to the current mode or using the function that is the value of variable `indent-region-function`. (Use `C-f indent-region` for more details.)
- **`C-x TAB`** (`indent-rigidly`): Indent the region text a fixed amount. With no prefix arg, you can repeat and back up using the `left` and `right` arrows. With a numeric prefix arg, indent that many chars (negative means reduce indentation).

If those keys do not seem to be bound as described then take a look at your init file, and adjust it accordingly.